# Android C++ Development with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, android, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mobile

I am trying to figure out how to setup android development with Visual Studio. I plan on using C++ (targeting 2.3 and above), but I see very little on the subject. Does anyone know how to do this?

I know that Android development suggests Java/Eclipse, however, I want to do C++/VS.

Comment: WRT your comments to trojanfoe's answer, I'll add my perspective on things...I've used VS for 5 years (C++ and C#). Until 4 months ago I'd never used Eclipse or programmed in Java. At the moment I'm writing an Android client (Java/Eclipse) / PC service (C#/VS2008). I have Eclipse and VS open right now and I'm switching between them as I fine-tune some things. Confusing sometimes? Yes, but Java/Eclipse with ADT is by far the best way to approach Android development IMO - it's tricky sometimes so I'd rather I could plug my device with USB and debug directly in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[vs-android](https://code.google.com/p/vs-android/)**

> vs-android is intended to provide a
>   collection of scripts and utilities to
>   support integrated development of
>   Android NDK C/C++ software under
>   Microsoft Visual Studio.
>
> Currently vs-android only works under
>   Visual Studio 2010. Earlier versions
>   lack the MSBuild integration with the
>   C/C++ compilation systems.
>
> The only required component is the
>   Android NDK. Neither Cygwin, Java, nor
>   the full Android SDK are needed to
>   compile and link C/C++ code.

Answer (score 4):

The Android NDK (Native Developmemt Kit) uses the GCC toolchain, so Visual Studio won't be any good unless you are willing to use it **just for editing** your source files and using some other external mechanism (Makefile from the Command Prompt?) to compile your program.

You should be able to use eclipse/CDT however, and this provides a very rich C/C++ programming environment (I use it everyday for Linux development).  See [here](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/348-get-your-eclipse-integrated-ndk-on).

Comment: Using `Visual Studio` just for editing seems like an overkill. There is emacs, Luke! :-)

Comment: I have been using Visual Studio for over seven years, going to use Eclipse is like programming in notepad to me. Is there anyway to setup android projects to open and compile in Visual Studio?

Comment: @jack: I agree, Eclipse is painful when ou're used to VS.

Comment: @jack: I'm pretty sure that VS will only work with the Visual C++ compilers and not GCC/G++.  You do Eclipse a disservice by comparing it to notepad however.

Comment: It's possible to set up makefile project in VC, that it will connect using ssh with linux box to do remote compilation. I've done it, the only problem is that you can't debug and also clicking on the error line in output window doesn't bring you to the code line.

Comment: If I want to use Visual Studio, is there an way I can debug my code with it?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://ian-ni-lewis.blogspot.com/2011/01/adventures-on-android-ndk-part-i.html) or [this](http://ian-ni-lewis.blogspot.com/2011/01/its-like-coming-home-again.html).